# Change all the values in dataframe without affecting the index

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

How can I replace all the values to 0, without affecting the index of the dataframe.

Here's an example code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.randint(10, size= 10), 'B':np.random.randint(10, size= 10), 'C':np.random.randint(10, size= 10), 'D':np.random.randint(10, size= 10)})

   A  B  C  D
0  6  5  3  8
1  0  1  1  9
2  9  3  0  7
3  1  9  1  9
4  3  5  7  5
5  0  5  3  2
6  8  8  7  9
7  6  2  9  5
8  5  8  8  0
9  9  4  7  2
```

Is there a way to do it using lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for some reason you really need to keep the original object, you could also use `df.loc[:]=0` but this could be a tiny bit slower than creating a new dataframe

Here is a quick comparison:

[image: comparison]

Comment: This puts things in perspective.

Comment: @RajNair that was the purpose of it ;) btw, may I ask why is the need to set all values to 0?

Comment: I just said 0 for this example, I had to make it to np.nan and then merge it with another smaller filtered dataframe, for purposes of plotting the data in a stylised way. Because np.nan doesnt show in the plot.

Answer (score 3):

The simpliest is create new `DataFrame` by constructor with pass index and columns from original DataFrame:

```
pd.DataFrame(0, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
```

Comment: Thats a good solution. But can we also do it using lambda function also?

Comment: @RajNair - Use `df.applymap(lambda x: 0)`, but it is slow.

Comment: I added a comparison of speed, applymap is really off